# Sum columns of a dataframe iteratively?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, math, multiple-columns

I am trying to write some code that will go through and add up Column 1 and Column 2, and replace the values in column 2 with that sum.  Then I want to add (the new) Column 2 and Column 3, and replace column three with the sum of those two values (and so on).  I am sure there is a better way to go about this but I think I need a some advice on how to accomplish this.

[Link to a sample of data.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mhIzcny0qf4lcd1uZlbZlYyLrp0cOzs1/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the manual way I can do this:

```
dfT = pd.DataFrame({
"Column 1": np.random.rand(4),
"Column 2": np.random.rand(4),
"Column 3": np.random.rand(4),
"Column 4": np.random.rand(4),})

print(dfT.head())

dfT['Column 2'] = dfT.loc[:,'Column 1':'Column 2'].sum(axis = 1)
dfT['Column 3'] = dfT.loc[:,'Column 2':'Column 3'].sum(axis = 1)
dfT['Column 4'] = dfT.loc[:,'Column 3':'Column 4'].sum(axis = 1)
print(dfT.head())
```

Here is the output from both print calls:

[image]

Is there a good way to loop through this process?  I am drawing a blank at the moment...
Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfT = pd.DataFrame({
    "Column 1": np.random.rand(4),
    "Column 2": np.random.rand(4),
    "Column 3": np.random.rand(4),
    "Column 4": np.random.rand(4),
})

print(dfT.head())
#    Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4
# 0  0.744905  0.831893  0.578289  0.759750
# 1  0.097360  0.436817  0.320901  0.620894
# 2  0.827297  0.653751  0.607263  0.712541
# 3  0.826755  0.841087  0.705164  0.738110

print(dfT.cumsum(axis=1))
#    Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4
# 0  0.744905  1.576798  2.155087  2.914837
# 1  0.097360  0.534177  0.855078  1.475972
# 2  0.827297  1.481048  2.088311  2.800852
# 3  0.826755  1.667841  2.373005  3.111115
```